# Spring Security Filter test, authentification not working in POSTMAN

Tags: authentication, spring-security, jwt, postman

I'm trying to check if attemptAuthentication is working but in postman but I'm getting 401 unauthorized.

My security Configure:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    //http.formLogin();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/login/**","/register/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/tasks/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


}
```

My attemptAuthentication:

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        AppUser appUser = null;
        try {

            appUser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), AppUser.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("****************************");
        System.out.println(appUser.getUsername());
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(appUser.getUsername(), appUser.getPassword()));
    }
```

My postman test:
[image]

My JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
package security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.example.springJWT.entities.AppUser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;



public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{


    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;    


    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super();
        //      super.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");

        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        AppUser appUser = null;
        try {

            appUser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), AppUser.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("****************************");
        System.out.println(appUser.getUsername());
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(appUser.getUsername(), appUser.getPassword()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User springUser=(User) authResult.getPrincipal();
        String jwt=Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(springUser.getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                .claim("roles", springUser.getAuthorities())
                .compact();
        response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX+jwt);
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post with username & password as key and value in header

Comment: I tried but still the same error

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 0):

in your JWTAuthenticationFilter class in the `attemptAuthentication` method you are providing a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to the auth manager

which has as principal a `String` instance and the in the `successfulAuthentication` method you are trying to cast this to an User

```
User springUser=(User) authResult.getPrincipal();
```

and this goes wrong if I try it but it depends on the AuthenticationProvider you are actually using

Comment: can you add logging.level.org.springframework.security= debug to your properties and add the log output when you call login with postman ?

Comment: thank but the problem was in the package itself, it was not visible for spring, I just changed it from security to com.example.springJWT.security , I do not know how I didn't realize that sooner ..